# jquery not able to read the value of my css attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is my css

```
 table.table tr td{
        padding:30px;
        border-left: double 1px white;
        border-bottom: double 1px white;
        cursor:cell;
    }
```

and this is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#zoomIn").on('click', function () {
        var previousValue = $(".table tr td").css("padding");
        console.log(previousValue);
        previousValue = previousValue + 10;
        console.log(previousValue);
        $(".table tr td").css('padding', previousValue);
    });
})
```

as you see, i log the value before adding `10` and after adding `10`

#### my problem

the first log gives me `an empty string` in firefox firebug. However, it should have given me `30`

what have i missed please?

Comment: have you tried using attr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be getting padding like this "" (empty string) so you will be adding 10 in it , not in 50

use these individual padding or if all are same you can take one of it

**Note**: In chrome .css("padding") will return 50px but in firefox it will return empty string while individual property will work on both

```
 top_padding =  $("body").css("padding-top");
 bottom_padding =  $("body").css("padding-bottom");
 left_padding =  $("body").css("padding-left");
 right_padding =  $("body").css("padding-right");
```

you will also need to parse padding

```
    parseInt($("body").css("padding-bottom"))
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you happen to know why `.css("padding")` works in chrome, but not in ff?

Comment: In chrome it will give 50px, but dont know wwhy is this a difference

Comment: when I use your solution, the first `log` works correctly, while the second log gives me `30px10`

Comment: `"30px" + 10 = "30px10"`, simple string concatenation. What you have to do is parse the padding value to int and then add the values.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli see edited answer, you need to parse it into int also

Comment: @maremp There is no specific reason, its just browsers has implemented different ways , Mozilla is most strict My suggestion for you, whenever you work for multiple browser, first to do coding for Mozilla if it works there, it will in mostly in other browser.

Comment: I didn't know that @Panther, thanks for advice.  I've always thought that Firefox is most advanced of all, but somehow it makes sense. When I'm coding javascript for browsers, I usually use test that run in all the browsers so I don't have to look for bugs afterwards.

Comment: It is better to test in all browsers , however just start with firefox. This is this firefox is most strict, it means it is working on firefox, it is standard.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using `parseInt` before adding to `previousValue`.

```
$("#zoomIn").on('click', function () {
    var previousValue = $(".table tr td").css("padding");
    console.log(previousValue);
    previousValue = parseInt(previousValue) + 10;
    console.log(previousValue);
    $(".table tr td").css('padding', previousValue + 'px');
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjan_borawake/8wmhegcs/)**

Comment: This doesn't work in ff.Check @A.B's answer to see the root of OP's problem.

Comment: ohh u mean to say using individual properties `padding-top`..... K. Using `parseInt` is what i wanted to say.. thanks.

Comment: pluss onee for the parsing issue

Answer (score 0):

When you set padding with css it actually gets parsed to 4 properties by browser `padding-left, padding-top, padding-right & padding-bottom`

In order to `get` the padding values you have to use those 4 sides. You won't get a return value for the top level `padding`